# Create NSPopUpButton Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nspopupbutton

How can I create an `NSPopUpButton` programmatically and attach the menu items to it?  This is what I have so far but it is not click able nor does it have any menu items attached

help window is just the name of my `NSWindow`

```
NSPopUpButton *button = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 0, 50, 50)];
[[helpWindow contentView] addSubview:button];
[button setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the designated initializer `initWithFrame:pullsDown:`, and then use `addItemWithTitle:` or `addItemsWithTitles:` to add the menu items

Answer (score 9):

You can also create an `NSMenuItem` then add it to the `NSPopUpButton`'s menu:

```
NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"menu" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];

[[popUpButton menu] addItem:menuItem];
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple one-liner does the trick for me:

```
[[popUpButton menu] addItemWithTitle:@"some title string" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
```